# JSF - p:tabView - changing tab and previous view still displayed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

Inside one tab, I can cilck on a button to display an "h:groupPanel". If I do this, and then change the active tab, the groupPanel that has just appeared is still visible, and appears on top of the now current tab.

The code for the tabView is:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="false" id="characterTabView">
    <p:tab title="View" id="viewTab">
         <ui:include src="/sections/character/view.xhtml" />
     </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Upgrade" id="upgradeTab">
        <ui:include src="/sections/character/upgrade.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

The "upgrade" page looks like

```
<h:panelGroup id="searchCompetencies" rendered="#{characterBean.rightPanel == 'searchResult'}">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="characterUpgradeLeft">
        <ui:include src="/sections/character/searchViewLeft.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="competencyCreation" rendered="#{characterBean.rightPanel == 'competencyCreation'}">
        <!--  The panel that is made visible -->
    </h:panelGroup>
```

And the page in which the component is made visible (searchViewLeft):

```
<p:fieldset legend="Create competency" styleClass="createCompetencyStart">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Create competency" type="button" onclick="toggleCreate()" update="upgradeTab" />
    </h:form>
</p:fieldset>
```

where "toggleCreate" changes the value of "characterBean.rightPanel".

Would you have any idea as to what I am missing here?

Thanks a lot :)